# how to toggle between font awesome icons jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

i want to togggle between to font awesome icons.I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#minus").click(function () {
         $("#tog").slideToggle();
         if (  $("#minus").hasClass("fas fa-minus")) {
             $("#minus").addClass("fas fa-plus")
         }else {
             $("#minus").addClass("fas fa-minus")
         }
     })
})
```

```
 $("#minus").click(function () {
         $("#tog").slideToggle();
         $("#minus").toggleClass("fas fa-plus")

     })
})
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#minus").click(function () {
         $("#tog").slideToggle();
         if (  $("#minus").hasClass("fas fa-minus")) {
             $("#minus").addClass("fas fa-plus")
         }else {
             $("#minus").removeClass("fas fa-plus")
         }
     })
})
```

but neither of the codes above works.How can i toogle between the two different icons

Comment: Which version of FA are you using? The latest version, using SVG, has issues dynamically changing the icon at runtime by changing the class

Comment: am using the latest the one with kits

Comment: If you're having difficulty, an alternative would be to add two button elements - one for expand, one for collapse then show/hide them as appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are adding new class but not removing the previous class when adding a new class so the element displays the icon class of which comes last in the stylsheet.

```
     $("#minus").click(function () {
         $("#tog").slideToggle();
         if (  $("#minus").hasClass("fas fa-minus")) {
             $("#minus").addClass("fa-plus").removeClass('fa-minus')
         }else {
             $("#minus").addClass("fa-minus").removeClass('fa-plus')
         }
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

A better implementation would be using [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#minus").click(function () {
         $("#minus").toggleClass( "fa-minus" );
         $("#minus").toggleClass( "fa-plus" );
     })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<i id="minus" class="fa fa-minus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```